# Error Script code failed (0x80040154) when debugging Visual Studio 2017 using Chrome

Tags: visual-studio, angular, google-chrome, visual-studio-2017

I have a Windows 10 laptop and am running Visual Studio 2017 (15.3.3).  When I try to debug my Angular 4 app hosted in an ASP.NET page I get an error stating Cannot debug some of the code in the process chrome.exe and that the WebKit code succeeded and Script code failed (0x80040154).  See error details below:

[image: VS 2017 Error]

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing it by uninstalling VS2017, deleting the C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio directory and then reinstalling VS2017.  This is not a great solution but it was the only one I found that worked.